# How can I hide the menu of Master page until the user do login in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, navigation, master-pages

I create a master page with a navigation bar. I made index page as a login page, so I use the login control in index.aspx which is registered under the master page.

Now my question is how can I hide the navigation bar which is in master page until the user do login, after the user doing successful login the navigation bar should appear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this in the Master Page (C# code)

```
<% if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) { %>

<div>navigation html when is authenticated</div>

<% } else { %>

<div>navigation html when is NOT authenticated</div>

<% } %>
```

Comment: thanks a  lot i use your idea but I write inside the if statement the following 
NavigationMenu.Items.Clear();

Answer (score 3):

In webforms you can use the [LoginView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display different content depending on the user's authentication status:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
   <div>Navigation Bar</div>
  </LoggedInTemplate>
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <div>Unauthenticated content</div>
  </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{        
        String path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        if (path == "/login.aspx")
        {
            Menu1.Visible = false;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Asp.net menu control, put the following code in page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu1.Visible = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

Otherwise put your navigation bar in a placeholder and show/hide the placeholder.

Comment: thanks i used NavigationMenu.Items.Clear() within the if statement.